# How can I accentuate values in this form to aid fast visual identification?

Tags: gui-design, design, data-tables, information, representation

My web app has a need to display multiple values.  Right now I find it hard to visually discern quickly.

Observe UI

[image]

Observe minimized html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>gpm</td>
    <td>rpm</td>
    <td>psi</td>
    <td>ft-lbs</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>3410.480271</td>
    <td>699.999</td>
    <td>55.095466</td>
    <td>50.454966</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>3410.480271</td>
    <td>50.4549</td>
    <td>50.607433</td>
    <td>55.095466</td>
</tr>
</table
```

I tried underlining the values, which kind of works to help delineate values, but not really, since it also makes the interface more messy.

For example, if you are looking for the last value of psi in the first (50.607...), is there a way to make it visually stand out amongst other values, for ease of reference?  Right now it is crowded between other values, which make it visually lost.   I am looking for numbers to not run into each other (not for any particular number to stand out).

To make things easier it is acceptable to format values up to first decimal point

Comment: What have you tried? What determines the "importance" of a value in your use-case?

Comment: I have tried `text-decoration: underline`, which looked a tad messy although acceptable in the worst case, and `background-color: lightblue`, which looked horrible. Importance is "not being lost in a wall of numbers when looking at the spread".  I can perhaps try "Excel" approach, where I emphasize borders of the cells.

Comment: Have you tried padding the table cells?

Comment: not yet but the thought have crossed my mind ... I think I would like some borders or some coloring or some accentuation though to go with the padding, to make it more distinguishable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using colors? if colors are not an options, then different shades of grey with different variations of weights should help.
remember, just because one column is important that does not mean other columns do no needs any effects(like less important columns could be made thinner or with different shades grey to reduce importance)

My suggestion, do this for alternate rows and use colors on hover or for very important columns.

Comment: to clarify, I am more so looking for ... all numbers not to run into each other.  Not for any particular number to stand out.

Comment: sorry..i meant alternate columns and not rows

Answer (score 0):

sparked by rajankz, I am thinking of perhaps doing alternate coloring on columns . ..

yep that worked: http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/css-table-color-columns.php

[image]